# (javascript) put the variable of function in p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to put the result of function in a `p` tag.

but I get a message like this

> "syntaxError: Unexpected identifier `($(#vol1).html(result);)`"

What's the problem?

It works well when I do `alert(result)` in the function.

```
<p id ="vol1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getResult(){
    var con1 = parseInt($('#concentration1').val());
    var vol = parseInt($('#volume').val());
    var con2 = parseInt($('#concentration2').val());
    var result = Math.round((con2*vol)/con1);
    $(#vol1).html(result);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `$` takes an object or a string, `#vol1` is not any type of data in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can check your code, #vol1 should be wrapped in quotes i.e. $('#vol1'). Everything else is perfect.

```js
function getResult() {
  var con1 = parseInt($('#concentration1').val());
  var vol = parseInt($('#volume').val());
  var con2 = parseInt($('#concentration2').val());
  var result = Math.round((con2 * vol) / con1);
  alert(result ? result : "not found"); // if result
  $('#vol1').html(result ? result : "not found");
}
getResult();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="vol1">12</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`#vol1` is missing quotes, must be `'#vol1'`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this,

```
document.getElementById('vol1').innerHTML = result;
```

or you can do this (via JQuery):

```
$('#vol1').html(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this: `$('#vol1')`

Or change to: `$('#vol1').append(result)`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?